# Returning Generic Type from a CreateInstance Method

Tags: c#, reflection

I seem to be having trouble finding a way to cast & return an Activator-created instance as its generic type.  I have looked at various examples...but cannot seem to find an "exact" example for what I am trying to accomplish.

- How do I return the correct type from the GetRepositoryInstance method below?

For instance...

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

}

public class TransactionProvider : ITransactionProvider
{
    public void AddPending(ITransaction transaction)
    {
        // Get the targeted types
        var typeEntity = GetTransactionEntityType(transaction.EntityName);
        var typePendingEntity = GetTransactionPendingEntityType(transaction.EntityName);

        // Get the Repository Instances for each type
        var repositoryEntity = GetRepositoryInstance(typeEntity);
        var repositoryPendingEntity = GetRepositoryInstance(typePendingEntity);
    }

    // -----
    // HERE...I want to return the generated type as its' IRepository<>...how?
    // -----
    private IRepository<> GetRepositoryInstance(Type entity)
    {
        var repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entity);
        var repository = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType);

        return repository;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: 
Of course, any solution still needs to be able to call methods of IRepository

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IEnumerable, IQueryable where TEntity : class
{
    #region <Methods>

    IQueryable<TEntity> AsQueryable();

    void Delete(TEntity entity);

    void DeleteList(IList<TEntity> entities);

    void DeleteAllOnSubmit(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

    void DeleteOnSubmit(TEntity entity);

    void Insert(TEntity entity);

    void InsertList(IList<TEntity> entities);

    void InsertAllOnSubmit(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

    void InsertOnSubmit(TEntity entity);

    void Update(TEntity entity);

    void UpdateOnSubmit(TEntity entity);

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: All you have is the type object. So, the answer to "how" is that you don't. C# is statically compiled, but you're working with a runtime type object. The best you can do is cast to some non-generic base interface if such an interface existed.

Comment: Why is this getting voted down?  This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no diamond operator in C# yet like in Java.

So you can't access the open generic type underlying to closed types, which prevents generic polymorphism.

You can try using a non generic interface as root where all IRepository Of T ihnerits from IRepository, which is untidy.

```
private IRepository GetRepositoryInstance(Type entity);
```

Comment: Doesn't work..."Using the generic type IRepository<TEntity> requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: What do you try?

Comment: It doesn't build...that (above) is the message

Comment: Do you try using MakeGenericType(typeof(entity))?

Comment: Or maybe MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(entity) })

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember is that `IRepository<>` is not a super-type of `IRepository<SomeEntity>`, and it's a type that can never be instantiated or assigned to, and can only be used as an argument to `typeof`.  `IRepository<T>` defines a set of separate types, unrelated by inheritance, each with its own static variables, and possibly it's own memory layout.

If you want substitutablity across a family of constructed generic types you need to introduce a common supertype (or just use `object`).  EG

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp30
{
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {

    }

    public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IRepository where TEntity : class
    {
    }

    public interface IRepository
    {
    }

    public interface ITransaction
    {
    }

    public interface ITransactionProvider
    {
    }

    public class TransactionProvider : ITransactionProvider
    {
        public void AddPending(ITransaction transaction)
        {
            // Get the targeted types
            var typeEntity = typeof(string);
            var typePendingEntity = typeof(string);

            // Get the Repository Instances for each type
            var repositoryEntity = GetRepositoryInstance(typeEntity);
            var repositoryPendingEntity = GetRepositoryInstance(typePendingEntity);
        }

        // -----
        // HERE...I want to return the generated type as its' IRepository<>...how?
        // -----
        private IRepository GetRepositoryInstance(Type entity)
        {
            var repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entity);
            var repository = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType);

            return (IRepository)repository;
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tp = new TransactionProvider();
            tp.AddPending(null);

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't build..."Using the generic type IRepository<TEntity> requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: It builds and runs in both .NET Framework and .NET Core.